# add additional column and place values based on a column in the same view

Tags: sql, view

I am trying to add an additional column named "Bucket" and place values based on the "Sales" column in sql database. If the sales is <0 I want to add the value 'Negative' and 'Positive' if it is greater than 0. What would be the most efficient way.

```
Year | Department | Sales | Bucket
2017   Marketing    $1000   Positive
2017   Accounting   $8000   Positive
2018   HR          ($5000)  Negative
2018   Sales       ($1000)  Negative
```

Comment: The most efficient way is to store numbers as numbers, not as formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case` expression for the new column:

```
case when sales like '(%' then 'Negative' else 'Positive' end as Bucket
```